# Не подключается метрика в шаблоне сайта

Tags: битрикс

Подключаю скрипт яндекс-метрики в футере сайта, примерно такого содержания:

```
<!-- Yandex.Metrika counter -->
<script type="text/javascript"> (function (d, w, c) {
        (w[c] = w[c] || []).push(function () {
            try {
                ...
            } catch (e) {
            }
        });

    })(document, window, "yandex_metrika_callbacks"); </script>
<noscript>
    <div><img src="..."
              style="position:absolute; left:-9999px;" alt=""/></div>
</noscript> <!-- /Yandex.Metrika counter -->
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в результате на сайте отображается noscript, расположенный в коде метрики, другие скрипты нормально работают на сайте
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S.
А если добавить какой-то скрипт, типа такого: `console.log('test');` то этот скрипт попадает в комментарий почему-то. И я не могу найти, где убрать этот комментарий. В шаблоне нет этого комментария
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1) у вас нету фтп доступа к сайту? лучше править там, нежели через админку.
2) чтобы не переносило в конец методами битрикса добавте `<script data-skip-moving=true>
      // Здесь скрипт который НЕ перенесется
</script>`

Comment: @Oleksandr, ваш ответ помог решить задачу, благодарю

Comment: добавил как ответ, буду благодарен, если отметите его верным

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы не переносило в конец методами битрикса добавте

`<script data-skip-moving=true> 
    // Здесь скрипт который НЕ перенесется 
 </script>`

Answer (score 0):

У вас включен режим переноса скриптов в конец страницы. Соответственно ищите подключение внизу.

Comment: обновил вопрос. 
Внизу скрипт почему-то попадает в комментарий. Как найти этот комментарий?

Comment: подскажите, как решить данную проблему?